# String or binary data would be truncated. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a store procedure that is giving me this error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

I found out the error is related to this line of my store procedure:

```
SET @ID = @@Identity
```

`@ID` value is 182452.

So I used `bigint` in `DECLARE`. But not sure why I still get this error.

This is complete piece:

```
DECLARE @ID bigint

INSERT INTO Email_Temp_Log ([_DateTimeInserted], [_DateTimeModified], [_Partitioner], [_IsActive], [inAppID], [inFromAddress], [inToAddress], [inTemplateID])
VALUES (getdate(), getdate(), 0, 1, @appID, @fromAddress, @toAddresses, @templateID)

SET @ID = @@Identity
```

when I comment out the

```
SET @ID = @@Identity
```

it is working fine.

Comment: Why do you think it is related to that `set` line?  The error is about character strings and that is a numeric operation.  More likely, it is due to the fact that some fields in the database are smaller than the variables being assigned to them.

Comment: I just guess and when I comment SET @ID = @@Identity it is not giving me this error any more.

Comment: not sure why but I have exact same code in another store procedure and it is working fine.

Comment: The code can be the same, but the DATA in the parameters can be different and are what is likely causing the error.

Comment: @StingyJack I used same data to test too:(

Answer (score 0):

You are misinterpreting the error. The error is coming from the insert statement. Perhaps you are not seeing the error without the final statement because the error is otherwise the final statement executed. Not sure exactly why.

The error is because 1 or more of the fields you are trying to insert are larger than the corresponding field declaration in the database.

Also, don't use @@identity any more (unless compact framework) use scope_identity() or use the output clause (sql2008+)